# EC2 UserData not working with Java SDK

Tags: java, amazon-ec2

I am trying to send some userData while spawning a new instance but unfortunately it is not working. The code is:

For debugging purposes, I have just used an echo statement, but I cannot find any new file generated on the machine. I also checked the cloud-init logs in /var/log folder, but none of them are present.

Can anyone help me to figure out a way to debug this problem or is there something crucial that I am missing?

I am using C4.8xLarge instances for the reference.

```
public static String getUserData() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
String userData = "";
userData = userData + "#!/bin/bash" + "\n";
userData += "echo  hello > hello" + "\n";

String base64UserData = null;
try {
    base64UserData = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(userData.getBytes("UTF-8")), "UTF-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return base64UserData;
}

RunInstancesRequest runInstancesRequest = new RunInstancesRequest();
runInstancesRequest.setImageId(AMI_ID);
runInstancesRequest.setEbsOptimized(true);
runInstancesRequest.setInstanceType(INSTANCE_TYPE);
runInstancesRequest.setMinCount(1);
runInstancesRequest.setMaxCount(1);
runInstancesRequest.withSecurityGroups("JavaSecurityGroup1");

runInstancesRequest.withUserData(getUserData());

List<BlockDeviceMapping> map = new ArrayList<>();
map.add(new BlockDeviceMapping().withEbs(new EbsBlockDevice().withSnapshotId("snap-af8s67ef").withIops(9000).withVolumeSize(300).withVolumeType("io1")).withDeviceName("/dev/sdf"));
runInstancesRequest.withBlockDeviceMappings(map);

RunInstancesResult runInsRes = ec2.runInstances(runInstancesRequest);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After creating an instance, go into the EC2 web console and view the user data on the instance. You should be able to view it as plain text in the web console. If it isn't there, or if it contains something other than the two lines you are trying to set as the user data, then you will know there is an issue with the way you are setting the user data.

If it is there and looks correct, then you will need to look into the cloud-init service log `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` on the created instance to see what the error is.

**Edit:** I just noticed you said the cloud-init logs are not present on the machine. What OS are you using for this server? It may not have the cloud-init service.

Comment: True. I used my own AMI which didn't have cloud-init installed in it. After installation, the script works. I don't see any output file named `cloud-init-output.log`. I suspect that is a AWS feature. In such cases, where can I check the output of my script and the fact that the script has run successfully or not?